# IPython display not displaying Markdown when notebook is run using nbconvert

Tags: html, markdown, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have the following in a Jupyter notebook cell:

```
import IPython.display as display


s = '# The World at Large'

display.display(display.Markdown(s))


s = '<b> The World at Large</b>'

display.display(display.HTML(s))
```

If I run it with shift+enter on the keyboard, I get:

[image]

However, if I execute the notebook with

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook.ipynb>
```

I get:

[image]

How do I get the Markdown to display like in the first image using nbconvert?

Answer (score -1):

After you run `jupyter nbconvert --execute`, your notebook is in an 'untrusted' state, which I believe is the cause of the issue you're describing. You can explicitly trust the notebook by running `jupyter trust <notebook.ipynb>`, which will allow your markdown output to render as expected.

See also [the official docs on security](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#security-in-notebook-documents), and  [this nbconvert issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/145).